# HTML/CSS image links don't work with absolute positioning

Tags: html, image, css-position, href, absolute

I'm making an epub3 fixed layout. Basically it is an HTML/CSS absolute positioning.

I'm trying to link the images to a website but the link doesn't work. It only works in the third image (img.seed).

It doesn't work in Chrome or firefox for example.

Here is code snippet:

```css
@font-face { font-family: "Source"; src: url("../fonts/Source.ttf"); }

body {
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}
p {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Source";
}
img.seed { top: 15.88%; left: 63.77%; }
img.bacteria { top: 15.39%; left: 7.32%; }
img.bee { top: 15.19%; left: 35.45%; }
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" lang="es">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=800, height=800" />
        <title>Tittle</title>
        <link href="../Style/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    
    <body epub:type="backmatter bibliography">
      <a href="http://www.booksbeck.com/travelling-seeds"><img class="seed" src="../Image/P999_seed.jpg" alt="page 23" /></a>
      <a href="http://www.booksbeck.com/bees-like-flowers"><img class="bee" src="../Image/P999_bee.jpg" alt="page 23" /></a>
      <a href="http://www.booksbeck.com/meet-bacteria"><img class="bacteria" src="../Image/P999_bacteria.jpg" alt="page 23" /></a>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Get rid of your negative z-index.

Comment: Thank you. Remove the negative z-index, it is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/chuux72f/

```
body {
    width: 800px;
    height: 800px;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
a {
    position: absolute;
}
a.seed {
    top: 15.88%;
    left: 63.77%;
}
a.bacteria {
    top: 15.39%;
    left: 7.32%;
}
a.bee {
    top: 15.19%;
    left: 35.45%;
}
```

remove your z-index and target the anchor tags, not the imgs

Comment: It works! Thank you!
The guide from  "Book Industry Study Group" recomended z-index=-1 so images are always in the background.